# Why a cronjob does not add a line to the csv file, but in case of direct execution as user 'Pi' the new line is added?

Tags: cron, raspberry-pi

I've a Python 3 script to add a line to a csv file.
If I execute the script as user `pi` a new line is added to the csv.
But if I run the save script by a cronjob, there is no line added to the csv.

`pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents/Projects/temperatureCheck/Data $ ls -la temperature.csv
-rw-rw-rw- 1 pi pi 328 Apr 25 13:47 temperature.csv`

```
00 9,15 * * * python3 /home/pi/Documents/Projects/temperatureCheck/temperatureCheck.py >> /home/pi/Documents/Projects/log/temperaturChecker.log 2>&1
```

but the push notification with pushbullet works.

Comment: Make sure that `/home/pi/Documents/Projects/temperatureCheck/temperatureCheck.py` exists.  `cron` will send notification by e-mail, check if any errors are reported.

Comment: Use `python3` with its full path. The `PATH` variable in your interactive shell may well be quite different from in the environment that cron provides.  Also check your email. The cron daemon ought to have emailed you error logs.

Comment: please check if you have this file `cat /var/spool/mail/pi`

Comment: the file `/home/pi/Documents/Projects/temperatureCheck/temperatureCheck.py` exists, but ther is no mail at `/var/spool/mail/pi`

Comment: May be a posting error, but the target file in cron entry lacks an e: temperaturChecker. Heck, it's also .log, not .csv.

Comment: Double check that the output file is writable by the root user (or even better: consider running your command with limited privileges, e.g. as user "pi").